# Обновление в html <table><tbody>тега tr</tbody></table>

Tags: php, javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать периодическое setTimeout(8 * 1000 ); обновление в таблице html, ну то есть в Mysql попала запись через какое то время на стороне клиента обновились tr-ки.

Я так понимаю с ajax js ? только вот проблема я с ним со всем со всем не дружу

Пример таблички ЗАРАНЕЕ СПАСИБО!!!!

```
<table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable" role="grid" aria-describedby="example2_info">
<thead>
<tr role="row"><th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Rendering engine: activate to sort column descending">Rendering engine</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Browser: activate to sort column ascending">Browser</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Platform(s): activate to sort column ascending">Platform(s)</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Engine version: activate to sort column ascending">Engine version</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example2" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="CSS grade: activate to sort column ascending">CSS grade</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr role="row" class="even">
<td class="sorting_1">Gecko</td>
<td>Mozilla 1.0</td>
<td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>A</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Пришло время подружится с технологией AJAX, без нее ни куда... Для этих целей лучше подойдет использовать фреймворк [jquery](https://jquery.com/), где все это можно упростить...